# Need code help on calling a macro from a new VTSO addin for Word

Tags: vba, vb.net, ms-word, vsto, ribbonx

I have created a new addin with a ribbon in MVS. On click of button1 I want to run a macro that is stored in a .dotm file in the Startup folder in Word. The .dotm file is called MyMacros and the macro is titled "TableMacro".

The module name in Word is titled NewMacros and the top rows of the macro in Word are:

```
Sub TableMacro()
`
` TableMacro
```

I am sure the macro is started with the code below but even this is guess:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Obeject, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
`code to call TableMacro'
End Sub
```

I know how to write macros but I have no idea the code needed to trigger the macro stored in the MyMacros.dotm file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search all global templates, including the Building Block template, from a VSTO add-in, you can use this:

```
        Dim wApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
        Dim i As Integer, Tmplt As Word.Template = Nothing
        For i = 1 To wApp.Templates.Count
            If wApp.Templates(i).Name = "MyMacros.dotm" Then
                Tmplt = wApp.Templates(i)
                wApp.Run(Tmplt.Name & "!TableMacro")
            End If
        Next
```

The value of performing it this way is you now have an object variable set to a specific global template and you can then get at AutoText, Styles, etc. and of course macros that are stored in that specific global template.

Answer (score 0):

Your VSTO code has a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application` object. Say you're storing that reference in a variable named `hostApp`, you could do this:

```
hostApp.Run("TableMacro")
```

That requires the .dotm file to be the "active" document. If the document isn't active and you have a reference to it (say, `theDocument`), I *think* this might work (untested):

```
hostApp.Run(theDocument.Name & "!TableMacro")
```

The object VB.NET uses is the same one VBA uses, so if `Application.Run "MyMacros!TableMacro"` works in VBA, it will work in VB.NET. I'd try to fiddle in VBA first to get the syntax right - you get instant feedback, vs needing to build and launch the host, load the add-in and test the thing with VSTO.

Answer (score 0):

The following `Run` syntax worked for me from within a VSTO Add-in to run VBA code in a Template loaded as an add-in. It uses the module name plus the macro name.

Keep in mind that `Run` can only work with public subs...

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Run("Module1.TestPublicVarx")
```